# Whats the best way to file transfer my site from server to a newer one?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, file-transfer

I have Windows 2003 server and i bought a new Windows 2008 server, i have more than 20 GB files want to migrate to the new server, i tried ftp, but its too slow.
There are any better ways?

Comment: Are they on the same local network?

Comment: FTP too slow?  What sort of network connection do you have between the servers?

Comment: Same hosting company, i think yes in the same network.

Comment: I mean FTP is too slow regarding to the large amount of files

Comment: @Amr, have you asked the hosting company if they will copy the data for you?

Comment: Yes, and will cost money, so i was trying to do my self before asking them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately your pretty much limited to FTP when it comes to moving large files remotely. To speed things up you could try using winrar to compress the data and split it into smaller chunks so that you can transfer a number at a time.

Other than that, the other option is to backup data to external drive and deliver it to new server.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming they are physically distant to each other, and that your connection is extremely slow (or that you have a very small patience). The faster and easier way would be to backup those files to tape/other media, and mail it to the remote location.

Comment: Never underestimate the speed of a truck full of backup tapes barreling down the highway.